# Prove that if for a sequence $a_n$ we have that $a_{n+1} >a_{n}$, then for $m>n$, $a_m>a_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

The problem is as follows.

Q: Let $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ be a sequence such that $a_{n+1} >a_n$. Prove that for two natural numbers $m$ and $n$ such that $m>n$, $a_m>a_n$.

I think I am misunderstanding this question because $a_m>a_n$ would just follow from the definition of the sequence and the definition of strictly greater than. The following was my attempt.

Proof:
Note that $m>n$ if and only if $m=n+c$ where $c\in N$ and $c \geq 1$. Because for any natural number $n$, $a_{n+1}>a_n$, it follows that $a_m >a_n$.

I feel like this is wrong and I am misunderstanding the question. This was the first problem in chapter 6 of Terence Tao's Analysis $1$. Could someone help explain if I am understanding the problem correctly.

Comment: Your proof just asserts the desired result.  Hint:  Use induction.

Comment: You aren't misunderstanding the question.  This *is* meant to be an obvious result.  And you have the right idea but your proof is not complete.  You have $a_{n+1} > a_n$ but you naven't proven that $a_{n+c} \ge a_{n+1}$.  (Use induction on $c$.)

Comment: " it follows that"  Why?  That's the key thing you really *must* explain: *WHY* does it follow that $a_m > a_n$.  Hint:  we *do* know that $a_{n} < a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n+c-1} < a_{n+c} = a_m$ and we do know that for ever $w: n \le w < m$ that $a_w < a_{w+1}$ but we have to put them all together and say the magic incantation of induction to make it a valid proof.

Comment: Oh I got it now. Thanks everyone for the help!